# One-box links in chat that have valid meta description and title tags

Tags: feature-request, chat, design, onebox

I was thinking about this a short while ago, to expand what links onebox in SE chat.

Essentially, anything that has a valid `<meta name="description" />` tag should be able to be one-boxed. The `<title>` could be used for the title of the box, and the meta description tag for the body. This could also (perhaps) be extended to the `<meta property="title">` as well (defined by RDFa 1.1), though I suspect this is less common.

Optionally, chat could also support the [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/) (`<og:meta>`) tags as well. Though these should only be used if the regular HTML `<meta>` tags cannot be used.

Comment: Oh, sorry for the wrong char!